# Element "align" is obsolete or non-standard: what should I use instead?

Tags: html, css, center, alignment

I have this HTML code:

```
<td align="center">
```

and I'm getting this error in Visual Studio 2008 from ReSharper:

> "Element '`align`' is obsolete or nonstandard"

What is the replacement of this code to make it standard?

Comment: I have this problem but on a massive scale and I'm currently looking for a way to automate the cleanup in Visual Studio.

Comment: It is worth noticing that `align` _is not deprecated_ in HTML 4.01, but _is obsolete_ in HTML 5. Not fair at all.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should use `text-align` in CSS rather than using the obsolete html styling attributes.

```
td{
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: And don't use it inline with the html, start being smart with classes for elements on the page and style them in a seperate css file :)

Comment: What if that doesn't work? For example, when trying to right align an ASPxButton in a table cell?

Comment: Assuming that an ASPxButton is an `<input>` or `<button>` you could just `float:right` the button within the table cell.

Answer (score 19):

That would be something like:

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
```

But it would be even better to move that style out of the html and put it in a separate style-sheet.

Answer (score 8):

You did not explain your goal, but using CSS is more modern...

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
```

Using that within a stylesheet, rather than inline would be even better...

```
td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use CSS, not element attributes.

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
```

You can also place this in an external style sheet:

```
td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with CSS?

```
text-align:center
```

Answer (score 1):

use css styling:

```
text-align:center
```

but styling tables doesn't really work well on ie6, if you need it

Comment: I’m pretty sure `td {text-align:center;}` works just fine in IE6.

Answer (score 1):

You could  try using `<td style="text-align: center;">`.  However, table elements themselves are not really recommended, so it might be Visual Studio's way of trying to force you to use the `<div>` element.

Comment: That depends on if the OP is using a table to display tabular data.

Comment: “table elements themselves are not really recommended” — that’s a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

#1 search result on Google for replacing deprecated `align="center"`.

For people like me looking for ways to center other elements (not just `<td>`) you may also need to add `width: 100%` to the style tag.

`<h1 style="text-align: center;width: 100%">`

Answer (score 0):

Any solution above did not work for me. What worked is the style below.

```
<td style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```

This is stated in below link as well.

https://sites.chem.utoronto.ca/chemistry/dstone/html/tables103.html

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer would be to migrate from

```
<td align="center"> .. </td>
```

to

```
<td class="center"> .. </td>
```

with a stylesheet.css

```
td.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

or

```
td.center {
  marign-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

depending on what kind of content needs to be centered.

See: [What is the difference between text-align: center; and margin: auto; ?](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/what-is-the-difference-between-textalign-center-and-margin-auto#:%7E:text=text%2Dalign%3Dcenter%20used%20to,the%20element%20itself%20to%20center.)